# VBA: Running Workbook_BeforeClose from general module and not ThisWorkbook of Active Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a macro I wrote that I want to run on close of the workbook.

Unfortunately, the only way to apparently do this is to place the macro in the `ThisWorkbook` module of the actual file as opposed to having it sit in the `PERSONAL.XLSB`.

This is not desirable for a few reasons:

1. The macro would have to be put into every workbook it needs to be run on--I have hundreds.
2. The workbooks would need to be saved as macro enabled which, in my experience, many email servers won't accept emails with macro enabled workbooks attached.

So ideally I would like to be able to run the macro from the `PERSONAL.XLSB` in just a general module.

Any suggestions about how this might be possible?

**EDIT:**

Per instructions at:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx

`PERSONAL.XLSB`

`CExcelEvents class module`

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox "New Workbook: " & Wb.Name
End Sub
```

`PERSONAL.XLSB`

`ThisWorkbook`

```
Private XLApp As CExcelEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set XLApp = New CExcelEvents
End Sub
```

<s>Doesn't work if you try to open a different workbook. If you click on `PERSONAL.XLSB` in recent documents it will trigger the message.</s>

Move this into another `ThisWorkbook` object for a specific workbook and it still only works on that workbook:

```
Private XLApp As CExcelEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set XLApp = New CExcelEvents
End Sub
```

So even though the class module is in `PERSONAL.XLSB`, it appears you still have to put the above into the workbook you want it to run on it, which I think I would still require saving it as an `.XLSM` and would run into email filter issues.

For some reason this did start working with everything in `PERSONAL.XLSB` although I didn't change anything. Exciting, but would like to know why.

However, now that I am trying to change the example to actually work how I need it with `BeforeClose`. So I updated to the following:

`PERSONAL.XLSB`

`CExcelEvents class module`

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Closing the workbook."
End Sub
```

`PERSONAL.XLSB`

`ThisWorkbook`

```
Private XLApp As CExcelEvents

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Set XLApp = New CExcelEvents
End Sub
```

Back to what happened yesterday... will only trigger when you go to close `PERSONAL.XLSB`. One would think that since the `PERSONAL.XLSB` opens with all workbooks, it would trigger regardless, but it isn't. Again, saving in the `ThisWorkbook` object of the target workbook works, but isn't a solution due to having to save as an `.XLSM` and email filters.

Comment: You can look at Application Events, which allow you to hook into 
 events at the Application level, using code which can be in your Personal.xlsb  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx

Comment: Still running into the same issue and it seems to only work when it is saved in the workbook you want to work on, not the `PERSONAL.XLSB`. Using the examples in the link, I can only get them to work if it I use the `ThisWorkbook` of the file. So I'd still have to insert into each workbook instead of just running everything from `PERSONAL.XLSB`.

Comment: Would help to show the code you tried...

Comment: Right, it is now updated.

Comment: You should leave your Personal.xlsb>>ThisWorkBook code as you had it originally (ie. using `Workbook_Open`).  The only job of that code is to create an instance of your `CExcelEvents`  class and hook it up to the Application object: it doesn't change, regardless of what events you want to monitor in your event handler class.

Comment: That did the trick my friend! If you want to post this as an answer, I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at Application Events, which allow you to hook into events at the Application level, using code which can be in your Personal.xlsb

Here's a good starting point:  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx